# Book about boy and animal going to top of world with interesting shape

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

My girlfriend vaguely remembers reading a book when she was in elementary school about a boy and an animal (she thinks it’s a donkey or a horse) traveling through the layers of an unusually shaped world (she thinks like a diamond or a spinning top).

In addition the world is separated by wealth, so the boy is going from the poorest section to the richest section. Have any of you heard of/read a book like this?

Comment: When was your girlfriend in elementary school?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots about the late 90’s to early 2000’s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Atherton: The House of Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atherton:_The_House_of_Power) by [Patrick Carman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Carman).

Though I read the books a long time ago, I'm fairly sure there wasn't a donkey. But there was an animal at one point that could be considered a companion (sort of):

> a dragon

Other than that:

1. The protagonist is a boy
2. The world is shaped like a layered spinning-top
3. The second layer and the top layer are separated by class (the second being agricultural and the top being noble).

Comment: *Atherton: The House of Power* by Patrick Carman?

Comment: John Rennie: that's what it sounds like to me (bar the donkey).

Comment: OK. Your answer could be improved by adding more detail about the story and a link to [the Wikipedia article on the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atherton:_The_House_of_Power). At the moment there isn't much for the OP to judge whether *Atherton* is a match or not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That’s it!! Thank you so much!